# Method to autoupdate Chrome Extension badge

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension that makes the badge show a number returned from an API. I have the code working fine, but I have it listening for DOMContentLoaded, so it only updates when the user opens up the extension.

I would like the extension to check the API every time the browser loads a page. I do not need to change anything in the page, I just want to use it for timing.

I'm not sure what I should be using, should I be using [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), or something else? What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The api you want for “every time the browser loads a page” is [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).  You’d have:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text":"ABCD","tabId":tabId});
});
```

An easy approach for development is to use a background page, get it working, and then figure out what changes you need [to convert it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition) to an event page.  With this stub however, nothing is stopping you from making it an event page.

Comment: Wonderful, I got my code to work. I made the js file into a background script, then gave it permission to "tabs". Thank you very much!

Comment: Depending on your use, you may be able to use "activeTab" instead of "tabs".  The former is more restrictive and doesn't cause a permission warning on installation.

Comment: I have a link in my extension that needs to open a new tab, so I need to have the "tabs" permission. Thank you for letting me know though!

Comment: @The_Grits you don't need the `tabs` permission to open a new tab.