# how to load a content script in chrome extension without clicking the extension icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extension development, and I want to create a simple extension which loads in every page and detect the current URL. If that URL is available a badge with the name of that website will appear.

**my manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Highlight some phrases",
    "description": "Hightlight some pre defined text from websql database after page loads",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png" ,
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "manifest_version":2
}
```

**my popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {

var tablink = tab.url;
    if (tablink.indexOf("google") > -1) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: "G"
        });
    } else chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: "No G"
    });


});
```

**my popup.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Set Page Color Popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="external.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I get the result I want when I click the icon in extension but I can't load the extension automatically like other extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are saying, you would like the extension badge to update on every page load. I asked a question about this a couple months ago, here's the link: [Method to autoupdate Chrome Extension badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949874/method-to-autoupdate-chrome-extension-badge)

Comment: Woow.. thanks it worked and also it worked by adding this line in manifest.json `"background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },`

thank you for answer